# Getting the primary, secondary and tertiary color of uivew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

Im using the following code to convert uiview to uiimage

```
- (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Then Im using the following code to get average color from the uiimage.

```
-(UIColor *)averageColorOfImage:(UIImage*)image{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char rgba[3];
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgba, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), image.CGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    if(rgba[2] > 0) {
        CGFloat alpha = ((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0;
        CGFloat multiplier = alpha/255.0;
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])*multiplier
                               green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])*multiplier
                                blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])*multiplier
                               alpha:alpha];
    }else {
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat)rgba[0])/255.0
                               green:((CGFloat)rgba[1])/255.0
                                blue:((CGFloat)rgba[2])/255.0
                               alpha:((CGFloat)rgba[3])/255.0];
    }
}
```

But it is always white though the uiview is of red color.

Why so? How can I be able to get the rgba color codes? or the primary, secondary and tertiary color of uiimage?

Comment: Your `rgba` array only has 3 elements, so you are overwriting memory. In a C array declaration you specify the count not the maximum index value, so you need to declare  `rgba[4]`.

Comment: can you please eloborate..thank you

Comment: Added an answer, but note the qualification I wrote in its first line - this may not be the only, or most significant, issue - hence the use of a comment initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one problem in your code, there may be others - this was spotted from a quick *read* of your code.

In your code you declare:

```
unsigned char rgba[3];
```

This declares a C-style (as opposed to Cocoa) fixed size array of *three* elements; those elements being accessible as `rgba[0]`, `rgba[1]` and `rgba[2]`. Your code goes on to use this as a *four* element array and uses `rgba[4]` which **does not** exist. There is no bounds checking on C-style arrays so your code will corrupt memory.

You need to declare the array to have four elements:

```
unsigned char rgba[4];
```

Comment: Well that's one issue fixed - memory overwriting - apparently there are more. Have you considered trying to reduce the image to something larger than 1x1px and then averaging the result? Maybe 1x1px is just too small. Or not reducing it at all?

Comment: No bro...because im converting an uiview to uiimage and then Im fetching the color from the converted uiimage

Comment: You are producing a 1x1px image, presumably because you assume that `CGContextDrawImage` will produce the average color of the image if you do that. What I am suggesting is that may not be the case. What happens if you produce a 16 x 16px image and average the 256 pixels yourself? Just a suggestion for you to explore.

Comment: ok bro....is it possible to break a uiview into multiple pieces and shatter it as in this image https://github.com/tyrantgit/ExplosionField/blob/master/explosionfield.gif

Comment: I have converted the uiview into uiimage so I can get the colour components and animate it while breaking

Comment: What you are trying is undoubtedly possible, you just have to figure out a method suitable for iOS and you've got an Android/Java method to get you started. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you...I have created it somehow..heheh thanks again